application's language issue on google play
I have published an application in Play store, and in Store Listing (in dev console) I have added Arabic translation to the existing English listing. Now when I search for the app in English it pops up as the first option which is perfect, but when I search in Arabic I can't find it at all. I tried and switched the default language to Arabic but nothing changed. I would really appreciate your help and suggestions
I tried searching in Arabic, but I can't find my application. I expect to find it in both languages.

How long ago did you try this? It might take a day or two to propage your change to Arabic.

It's been more than a week, and I tried deleting the English and leaving only the Arabic. But when I search in Arabic, it still doesn't appear, and when I search in English, the application appears with the Arabic name.
